# Confusion about this explanation of the radial hydrogen Schrodinger solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen, asymptotics

I was reading [this page](https://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/327/hatom.php#rad-soln) about solving the radial part of hydrogen's energy eigenstates.  They explain how to solve for the asymptotic behavior $R_{\infty}(r)$ first by taking the limit of the differential equation itself, which I thought was a cool idea.  This gives the decaying exponential.  Then we assume $R(r)$ of the form

$$R(r) = R_{\infty}(r)\ \sum_{q=0}^{\infty} b_q r^q$$

But they don't show the steps after that, instead just saying that when you plug it back in and enforce series convergence, you get a discrete solution set.

Well, I guess we know that the series you end up with are the "generalized Laguerre polynomials", right?  But in what sense do these respect the asymptotic convergence?  Yes, the overall function goes to zero asymptotically, because the exponential always wins.  But now I would think the asymptotic behavior is $r^n$ times the exponential, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial.  And that does not solve the asymptotic equation.  In order to do that, the power series itself should have a horizontal asymptote at 1!  Which all Laguerre polynomials, other than the first, do not.  What gives?

Comment: The infinite series actually wins over the exponential if it doesn't get truncated.

Comment: @MengCheng  Ah, I get it.  And furthermore it *does* solve the asymptotic equation because we only keep the highest order terms in the derivatives of $R$.  Thanks!

Comment: $R_{\infty}r^{n}$ should solve the original equation *approximately*, i.e. in the limit of large $r$.  Note that, because there is a boundary condition at $r=0$, the next step is to write $r^{\ell+1} R_{\infty} g(r)$ where $g(r)$ will be a polynomial which goes to a constant for small $r$.